# Like statement or removal of trailing blanks in html agility pack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I m trying to download data from a website into a datatable. The problem is I cannot access the right node because there seem to be blanck spaces. Here is my code so far:

```
        public static DataTable downloadtable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string htmlCode = "";
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "AvoidError");
            htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://www.eex.com/en/Market%20Data/Trading%20Data/Power/Hour%20Contracts%20%7C%20Spot%20Hourly%20Auction/Area%20Prices/spot-hours-area-table/2013-08-22");
        }
        //this is just to check the file structure from text file
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\temp\\test.txt");
        file.WriteLine(htmlCode);

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);

        dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='list electricity']/tr/th[@class='title'][.='Market Area']"))
        {
            //This is the problem name where I get the error
            foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("//td[@class='title'][.='            00-01          ']"))
            {

                        foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("//td"))
                        {
                                //this is to check for correct result, final result would be to dump it into datatable
                                Console.WriteLine(cell.InnerText);                             
                        }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

I m trying to download the Hours prices from the link in the code but it seems to fail because of trailing blanks (I think).
Is there a like statement for the name of a node? Or can you remove trailing blanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are trying to retrieve `td`'s from inside a `td` node which obviously doesn't have more `td`'s.

```
<tr>
 <td class="title">         00-01           </td>
 <td class="spacer"></td>
 <td class="r">€/MWh</td>
 <td class="spacer"></td>
 <td>35.34</td>
 <td class="spacer"></td>
 <td>34.02</td>
 <td class="spacer"></td>
 <td>34.02</td>
</tr>
```

So if you try to iterate with your result `table.SelectNodes("//td[@class='title'][.='            00-01          ']")` it will contain no td's inside of it.

**If you want all the rows starting from 00-01** you can use this one:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
foreach (HtmlNode row in doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='title'][(normalize-space(.)='00-01')]/ancestor::table"))
{
    foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("./tr/td"))
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.InnerText.Trim()))
            continue;
        Console.WriteLine(cell.InnerText.Trim());
    }
}
```

If you want only the 00-01 row you can use this one:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='title']"))
{
    if (row.InnerText.Trim() == "00-01")
    {
        foreach (var cell in row.ParentNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.InnerText.Trim()))
                continue;
            Console.WriteLine(cell.InnerText.Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can use it as:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
foreach (HtmlNode row in doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='title'][(normalize-space(.)='00-01')]"))
{
    foreach (var cell in row.ParentNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.InnerText.Trim()))
            continue;
        Console.WriteLine(cell.InnerText.Trim());
    }
}
```